# Chrome monitorEvents doesn't work on website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to analyse the following website for when certain events are happening by using monitorEvents: https://www.ea.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/

I've tried just elements, but also document. It does not show any events at all. Any ideas why this can be. And if this doesn't work, is there any other way to do it?